# How to modify the following Dijkstra/ Uniform-cost search to return the result for all end points?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, artificial-intelligence, python, dijkstras-algorithm

I know there is a lot of code out there that does this, but in particular, I'm trying to modify the following code to not just return the goal node/ one end point, but all endpoints. How do I go about it? I tried thinking of keeping a seen/visited set, but that seems redundant and kills the whole point of the reached map.

```
def best_first_search(problem, f):
    "Search nodes with minimum f(node) value first."
    node = Node(problem.initial)
    frontier = PriorityQueue([node], key=f)
    reached = {problem.initial: node}
    while frontier:
        node = frontier.pop()
        if problem.is_goal(node.state):
            return node
        for child in expand(problem, node):
            s = child.state
            if s not in reached or child.path_cost < reached[s].path_cost:
                reached[s] = child
                frontier.add(child)
    return failure
```

Comment: What are you trying to calculate? Since you just return the node or `failure`, it seems to me that it is just a weirdly worded graph traversal and not Dijkstra's algorithm. Your algorithm makes comparisons with `path_cost`, but those costs are never modified. If you want to compute path costs, then just run the algorithm until the frontier is empty (and don't forget to modify costs). If you want the paths that reach those costs, use a predecessor array.

Comment: @Nathaniel this code is from the official author of the AI textbook (Norvig's github), so I am sure it is correct. I assume it is modified by doing reached[s] = child (implicit tree)

Comment: hmmmkay… That's weirdly worded. As for what you want, I think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm without step 5 is enough.

Comment: `this code is from the official author [Norvig's github]` Please refer it in the post proper more formally](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), include the code block in a block quote.

Comment: (While it is useful to assume information from a *reputed source* correct, same goes for staying aware it's an assumption.)

Comment: Change `return node` to `yield node` (and remove `return failure`).